# Where to find the documentation to the get value method?

Tags: c#

I use a `Dictionary<int, int> a` and use `a[0]` to get the value for the key `0`. Under which method name can I find the documentation about the `a[0]` behavior?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the meaning of _documentation of the get value_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a method. You're looking for the *indexer*, which is more akin to a property.

- [Dictionary indexer documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [General information on indexers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.